# Tiny Integer Space allocation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqldatatypes

I am a bit confused on how `tinyint` data type size is allocated in SQL Server.

I have created table `Temp` and iterated the values `255` over `10000` times. I got the output in reserved column as `136 kb` and data as `120 kb`.

When I iterate the same value `255`over `12000` times, I got output in reserved  column as `200 kb` and data as `144 kb`.

```
drop table TEMP
GO

create table TEMP
(
    ids tinyint
)
GO

insert into TEMP
values('255')
go 10000

sp_spaceused 'TEMP'
go
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server stores rows on 8KB pages.

All of the rows you have created are identical and look as follows

```
10 00 05 00 FF 01 00 00 00
```

- `10` Status Bits A
- `00` Status Bits B
- `0500` Column count offset
- `FF` - the actual tiny int
- `0100` - column count
- `00` - Null bitmap
- `00` - Padding to meet the [9 byte minimum row size](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14854/3690)

Note that the tinyint value itself just takes 1 byte per row and there is an additional 8 bytes of metadata per row.

Additionally there is overhead on the page for a 96 byte page header and additional 2 byte per row overhead in the footer for the slot array.

As a result SQL Server can only store a maximum of (8192-96)/11 rows per page (736) and in reality after the 700th row is inserted and the page is >95% of capacity then the PFS page reports the data page is [`100_PCT_FULL`](https://sqlity.net/en/2377/pfs/) so that is the max number of rows per page achieved here with singleton inserts.

10000/700 means that it requires 14.3 pages to store the rows. In SQL Server 2012 the first 8 pages will be allocated from mixed extents and then pages are allocated in full extents.

So probably your 136 KB will consist of 17 8 KB pages as follows

- 8 pages in mixed extents
- 1 IAM page
- 8 pages from a uniform extent (with 1.7 pages free)

Once the 1.7 pages are filled up a new uniform extent will be granted. This is 64KB and explains the jump from 136 KB to 200 KB